# something like same "tag" for multiple commits

Tags: git

My dilemma: I always want to mark the last reviewed commit so that I can always specify the diff.
I let my code to be reviewed only after certain time. How can I remember the last time I had my code reviewed?

My idea was to always tag: "reviewed" the last reviewed commit. However I'd prefer to have the opportunity to tag commits with this as-I-go. Without the need to always delete the tag. +I'd like to remember which diffs I had for reviewing.

So it would be the best if I could tag multiple commits with the same "tag". Unfortunatelly tag is something like an "ID" in DOM. I'd prefer something like  "class" in DOM. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate a tag based on the current date/time:

```sh
$ git tag review-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

This generates a tag like this:

```sh
$ git tag -l
review-2015-04-30_17-20-03
```

You can also define this as a git alias:

```sh
$ git config alias.tag-review '!git tag review-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")'
```

Now use

```sh
$ git tag-review
```

Comment: after this exportation, this line in .gitconfig appeared: tag-review = tag review-2015-04-30_17-33-43

Comment: so a constant thing - how can I make it non-constant? (so that it would dynamically update the date?)

Comment: super, thanks. And can I do something like "git diff LAST_REVIEW..HEAD" ? without writing the complete review tag name? No problem if not :) (btw will check this + mark this as an answer in a couple of hours, after I try it out)

Comment: Well.. shell autocompletion? But maybe you really want to make some small script that deletes the review tag and adds it again.

Comment: @StephenKing I think if you do `git tag review-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") && git tag -f reviewed`, you would be able to provide the desired behavior to OP. The reviewed tag would point to the last such tag made, while all previous tags would still be there.

Comment: Ah, indeed, there is a `-f` (force) option for `git tag`. I think that's even better.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to check [`git notes`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html).

Comment: `git notes --ref review add -m "Reviewed"`, this adds a note at current commit. `git notes --ref review list`, returns a list of "HASH-Message HASH-Commit". To see those notes in the log use: `git log --notes=review`.

Comment: NB: notes aren't fetched and pushed by default.

Comment: @ruvim the same with tags.